# If file exists, send Email and run batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a script that runs every two hours to see if a file has been dropped.  If it is there, I get an alert.  I would like to take it a step further and run a job the move the file.  So far here is what I have:

```
$path       = "\\0.0.0.0\files\test\state\WAITING\*"
$fileexists = Test-Path $path   
if ($fileexists) {
  Send-MailMessage `
    -From noreply@email.com `
    -To tester@foo.com `
    -Subject "Files Have Arrived" `
    -Body "The files have arrived and are being moved to the processing folder." `
    -SmtpServer 0.0.0.1
} else {
  #donothing
}
```

I want to fit this in the ifexists:

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c \\0.0.0.0\files\test\MOVE.bat"
```

Would it be like this:

```
$path       = "\\0.0.0.0\files\test\state\WAITING\*"
    $fileexists = Test-Path $path   
    if ($fileexists) {
      Send-MailMessage `
        -From noreply@email.com `
        -To tester@foo.com `
        -Subject "Files Have Arrived" `
        -Body "The files have arrived and are being moved to the processing folder." `
        -SmtpServer 0.0.0.1
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c \\0.0.0.0\files\test\MOVE.bat
    } else {
      #donothing
    }
```

Comment: So... what is the problem?

Comment: Rather than write a batch file, you should consider using a PS native cmdlet to move the file(s).  `Get-Help Move*`

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out

```
$path       = "\\0.0.0.0\files\test\state\WAITING\*"
$fileexists = Test-Path $path
if ($fileexists) {
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c \\0.0.0.1\files\test\MOVE.bat"` | Send-MailMessage -From noreply@test.com -To tester@foo.com -Subject "Files Have Arrived" -Body "The files have arrived and are being moved to the processing folder." -SmtpServer 0.0.0.2`
} else {
#donothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use semicolon ";" to separate commands.